# Freezing a meringue?

Tags: eggs, freezing, meringue

Can a meringue ever be frozen?  I want to make a meringue topped dessert for Easter and don't want to leave my guests while I add the meringue and torch it.  Ideas?

Comment: If you share some more detail of what you are making, perhaps we can offer some alternative approaches that might help.

Answer (score 3):

I am inferring that this is a soft meringue, not a dried one.

These do not freeze well as the ice crystals forming will disrupt the foam, and they will weep and deflate.

This sort of meringue really does need to be done at the moment of service.